# Resource for learning sequences and series.

Tags: sequences-and-series, soft-question, online-resources

By reading various questions and answers on this site, I realized I'm particularly weak at sequences and series, for example various tests for convergence tests, Cauchy sequences and so on. It's mostly because in the calculus courses that I took, this part was always ignored or skipped. That's why I'm thinking about learning this myself. Can someone provide some (preferably online) resources for this? Note that I have background in single variable calculus.

Comment: Elements in Real Analysis,Robert G Bartle

Comment: Read from this book and work out more problems.